# Trying to install Windows on an M.2 drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, ssd

I just bought new disks for my computer and got an M.2 SSD as well. I was thinking about doing a fresh installation of Windows, and using the M.2 SSD as a Windows drive.

I put my bootable USB into the computer, and when I got to the question "Where do you want to install Windows?" the computer didn't find any drives at all. The only strange part is why it can't find the M.2 drive because the other two drives I disconnected for now.

Then I entered the BIOS to check if I got any results there. The drive was available in the BIOS, but not in the Windows install.

I'm using M.2 [this adapter](https://inetimg.se/img/452x339/5406030_0.jpg) and a Gigabyte GA-Z97P-D3 motherboard.

Comment: "So i put my bootable usb into the computer and when i got the question "Where do you want to install Windows" the computer doesn't find any disks at all." - This indicates you didn't boot the disk in UEFI only mode.

Comment: How to do this @Ramhound ?

Comment: You can find the "Enable UEFI" setting in the BIOS.  Usually it's a switch or separate lists , UEFI or legacy.